# When training GANs in Keras, are multiple passes required to optimize the generator and discriminator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm more familiar with tensorflow graph training than Keras, but I'm trying out Keras here.

In building a GAN the generator needs be optimized against a different loss than the discriminator (the opposite loss). In base tensorflow this is easy enough to implement using either 2 optimizers or by calling `optimizer.compute_gradients(...)` and `optimizer.apply_gradients(...)` separately with the appropriate group of weights.

In Keras, I don't see that I can achieve either of these. In implementations such as [Keras-GAN](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/infogan/infogan.py), it appears that the training of generator and discriminator are split into separate models and then trained independently batch-by-batch. This means many more passes are required per effective update than would be required with the base tensorflow implementation with two optimizers operating on one pass.

Is there a way to implement the optimizer for GANs so that both generator and discriminator get trained in one pass in Keras?

TF 1.14

Comment: Would it be possible to provide (or point to) an example in TF where GANs are implemented using `optimizer.compute_gradients(...)` and `optimizer.apply_gradients(...)`? Also, how does having 2 optimizers in TF differ from splitting the GAN into separate models in Keras, exactly? (I'm not familiar with the TF implementation)

Comment: The primary performance difference is the need for two forward pass computations when you use two models. Also in Keras you have to use `train_on_batches` which doesn't support any of the fancy distributed mode training, so the value-add of Keras is diminishing. I don't have a full implementation example, but here is a small code snippet where I was comparing individual updates to combined updates (a bit derivative to your question, I was doing testing for a multi-task model here, it may be a useful snippet to illustrate one-step gradient updates in TF base): https://pastebin.com/BAuCbeQd

Comment: What GAN loss you're using? Are both loss functions passed through the discriminator?

Comment: I haven't specified the GAN because the model I'm building is a combination of autoencoder and GAN components and I want to keep the question simple, but the added complexity I'm dealing with only exacerbates my concern about duplicate computation. But you can think InfoGAN for the questions purposes, it's not so far from what I'm doing. And yes, the generator loss must pass through the discriminator (I wasn't actually aware that an architecture exists that doesn't function that way?).

Comment: This is a really tough question for Keras... training mechanisms and optimizer working are buried very deep in the source code (especially if you're using tf.keras where the `OptimizerV2` is being used). To the point that it should actually be a lot easier to use the tf style you proposed.

Comment: Using two optimizers would require changing the source code. Using a custom optimizer that separates the weights would still face the problem of not knowing for which loss it's calculating the gradients (probably all losses together).

Comment: My suggestion is: build the Keras models as you would (but don't compile them). Create the losses in tensorflow style and train with tensorflow optimizers.

Comment: @DanielMöller, after ruminating on this for the past week, I think that is probably the best answer to the question, if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept that. It does make inference and saving operations a little easier, and at least standardized, and it does enforce a good code structure to the modeling process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really tough question for Keras for several reasons:

1. A model can only have one optimizer... it would be necessary to change the source code for it to accept two or more
2. Even when you are using a custom optimizer, it would be possible to separate the weights, but it doesn't offer support to separate the losses, as can be seen in the [source code for optimizers](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L157). The probability is that the optimizer already computes a final common loss (which would then make it impossible to attribute one loss for a group of weights and another for the other group)
3. The training mechanisms are not easy to find in the code. Things are spread all around, supporting many things such as loss weights, sample weights, etc. The time that it would take to summarize everything and then decide what to do/change would be too much.

### Answer suggestion

Make your model in Keras as you would. The discriminator, the generator, their connections and outputs.

Just don't compile it. Instead, keep track of the main tensors (generator output, discriminator output, generator input), create the loss functions in Tensorflow style and train everything in tensorflow style.